# Read-only filesystem Recovery Mode not working

Tags: boot, 14.04, read-only

I have seen other posts of this before, but they didn't help. In short, today I was trying to play Colobot on my Ubuntu Trusty computer, when I tried to access the directory the game was in by terminal, bash warned me that the disk was in a read-only state.

I reboot and boot into recovery mode, there I did `fsck`, it threw errors, but apparently failed to fix them. At that point I was getting annoyed and searched the internet, once I found an answer, I ran the grub and dpkg options in recovery mode, recovery mode said it was read/write, but when I boot in, I get the same thing, read-only. So I reboot into recovery mode, and tada! It's read-only again. I can't think of anything else to do, as the other people who had the same problems had them fixed by the steps I did. I got all my important files backed up to both a separate partition and a separate computer, so no worries there.

I just need help getting this to work, as my computer might as well be a brick if I cant do f/a on it